# NLog Rules are not respecting MinLevel

Tags: nlog

I have a project that someone else wrote that uses a ton of Logger.Debug calls. I want to filter out all the Debug calls from our log files, however, the rules I have set up seem to be ignored. All log levels are being logged to all targets, regardless of me setting the MinLevel to "Error"

I've tried a bunch of things, including creating a "Black hole" rule. I still get Trace, Info, and Debug entries in our logs.

Here is the current config:

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwConfigExceptions="true">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NTRPRS.NLog.Slack" />
  </extensions>

  <targets async="true">
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logfile.txt" />
    <target xsi:type="Slack"
            name="slackTarget"
            layout="${message}"
            webHookUrl="[somehookurl]"
            channel="#logs"
            excludeLevel="false"
            embed="true"
            username="Sync NLogs"
            icon=":hurtrealbad:" />
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="logfile, slackTarget" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Your config looks valid. Are you sure this is config used? (e.g. maybe there is a 2nd config in the bin folder for example)

Comment: Yes, I am certain. I still haven't gotten this resolved :(

Comment: Please check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting